# How can I list the available qualities of a YouTube video to the user?

Tags: python, pytube

I'm working on a Pytube YouTube downloader and I wanted to make sure that when the user pastes the YouTube video link, they will get the available qualities of the video and choose one, I need help on how to do this and if I can also show them the size of each one it will be good to helping me to do it.

Comment: Did you try anything at all? Did you check the [docs](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#working-with-streams)?Each stream has a `res` field

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes i did read the documentation from pytube, and i know there is a res field but i don't know how to get just the "480p" or something .... i don't want the full <Stream> tag

Answer (score 1):

The [`streams`](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.YouTube.streams) attribute will give you a list of all the available streams of each YouTube object.

You might want to [filter](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/streams.html#filtering-streams) that list according to what you want exactly (video/audio, progressive/adaptive), but anyway, keep in mind that there might be repeating qualities due to different encodings and such. For this, we will use a set:

```py
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo')  # Download YouTube Rewind 2019
streams = set()

for stream in yt.streams.filter(type="video"):  # Only look for video streams to avoid None values
    streams.add(stream.resolution)

print(streams)
```

Will give:

```
{'720p', '144p', '1080p', '240p', '480p', '360p'}
```

After the user chooses the resolution they want, you can use it to further filter the streams:

```py
for stream in yt.streams.filter(resolution="720p"):
    print(stream)
```

Will give:

```
<Stream: itag="22" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="24fps" vcodec="avc1.64001F" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
<Stream: itag="136" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="24fps" vcodec="avc1.4d401f" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="247" mime_type="video/webm" res="720p" fps="24fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="398" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="24fps" vcodec="av01.0.05M.08" progressive="False" type="video">
```

Comment: Is it possible to download video progressive="False" ?  Tomerikoo